# iOS swift connect TLS socket with cert per string

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

I have created an RSA certification using a generated private/public key using this library-
https://github.com/cbaker6/CertificateSigningRequest

thanks to this library I now have a certificate in a PEM string format.
now I want to create an ssl socket that can use this certificate to connect to a remote server that requires an ssl connection.

so for example this is a pseudo code in node.js:

```
let options = {
                key : this.certs.key,
                cert: this.certs.cert,
                port: this.port,
                host : this.host,
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
            }

            console.debug("Start Connect");
            this.client = tls.connect(options, () => {
                console.debug(this.host + " connected")
            });
```

where the `key` and the `cert` are both a PEM string

I tried `BlueSSLService` lib, but they only support connecting with cert files, no strings.

Comment: Were u able to solve the above issue.

Comment: Just in caes you still were looking, check out this guy's implementation https://github.com/vapor-community/tls/blob/master/Sources/AppleTLS/AppleTLSClient.swift

Technically it's depreciated in favour of Network.framework, but the documentation on that is so crap. Even Apple's official ssl socket guide still references the old commands :/ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secure_transport/using_the_secure_socket_layer_for_network_communication

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? 
I have the same issue to connect to an Android tv :)